Shopify not providing authorisation code to transfer domain
I’ve had my domain registered with shopify for about 5 years as I ran an e-commerce shop with them. My domain renewal is coming up soon and I asked for the authorisation code to transfer it to a new domain host as I’m no longer running a shopify store. However it’s been over two weeks and they’ve just been sitting on my transfer request. There is no way for me to request the code through their platform as the domain is not visible for some reason. Their customer service team said they think another shopify store fraudulently claimed my domain but I need to wait for a response from their domain team. I now have just one week left till it expires with no response to my numerous emails to shopify. Is there any way I can force them to provide the authorisation code. I’m not sure what my options will be once the domain expires and am keen for that not to happen. Complaints have already been raised with icann and tuscow (who shopify use for domains) but who knows how long that will take.

If it's not visible in your account, your domain is in the hands of Shopify support, unfortunately. If it's an expensive domain, you could consider a lawyer. Good news is that most TLDs have a grace period of at least 30 days after expiry for renewal, so the domain shouldn't immediately go anywhere the day it expires (check that your domain's TLD has this protection.)

Since you've already raised complaints with ICANN and Tucows, try reaching Shopify through social media or escalate via legal channels if necessary. Additionally, ensure your domain auto-renews to avoid expiration while waiting for a resolution.
